# INSERT ALL with parallel hint

Tags: sql, oracle

I need parallel insert with INSERT ALL statement:

```
INSERT /*+ APPEND NOLOGGING PARALLEL(A,4) PARALLEL(B,4) */ ALL
WHEN COL1 NOT LIKE '123%' THEN INTO SCHEMA.TABLE1 A
WHEN COL1 LIKE '123%' OR COL2 LIKE '5%' THEN INTO SCHEMA.TABLE2 B
SELECT /*+ PARALLEL(C,4) */* FROM SCHEMA.EXTERNAL_TABLE C;
```

But when I use table alias (SCHEMA.TABLE1 A) getting error "missing SELECT keyword"

How can I do that?

Comment: By "table hint" did you mean "table alias"? (By the way, `nologging` is a table property, not a hint.)

Comment: Sorry, "table alias" like this: "schema.table X"

Comment: Also the query above is missing the list of expressions between `select` and `from`. It needs to select something.

Comment: Sorry again, fixed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
insert /*+ append parallel(table1,4) parallel(table2,4) */ all
    when col1 not like '123%' then into table1
    when col1 like '123%' or col2 like '5%' then into table2
select /*+ parallel(c,4) */* from table3 c;
```

I removed the `NOLOGGING` comment as it's confusing within the hint list.

Parallel INSERT uses direct path anyway so the APPEND is redundant.